# Is there a way to activate/run script when disconnected from wifi hotspot?

Tags: wireless-networking, script, shell-script, automation, automator

This script works perfectly to reconnect the lost Wi-Fi signal/connection. Is there a way to auto-activate/run this script every time my Mac is disconnected from the Wi-Fi hotspot?

```bash
    #!/bin/bash
      if [ $(networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi | grep -c 'IP address:') = '1' ]
      then networksetup -setairportnetwork en1 <networkName> <passwordToNetwork>
    fi
```

What can I do?